# socket.io request event emitted, how to find the callback to handle the request event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

It looks like the line below emit 'request' event, supposedly there's callback function to handle the 'request' event. However, I cannot find location of that callback. Can you help for that?

Thank you.

[project]
https://github.com/openhab/openhab-cloud

[file]
app.js

[line]
io.sockets.in(req.openhab.uuid).emit('request', {

[reference]
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { logger: logger });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code that you link to [here](https://github.com/openhab/openhab-cloud/blob/master/app.js#L570):

```
// Send a message with request to openhab agent module
io.sockets.in(req.openhab.uuid).emit('request', {
    id: requestId,
    method: req.method,
    headers: requestHeaders,
    path: requestPath,
    query: req.query,
    body: req.rawBody
});
```

sends a `request` message with data to every currently connected socket.io client that is in the `req.openhab.uuid` room.  A client-side connection would listen to that message with client-side code like this:

```
socket.on('request', function(data) {
    // this is the callback function I think you were asking about
    // put code here to process the data
});
```

where `socket` is the client-side socket.io connection.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But I can NOT find **socket.on('request'**, how can that be?

Comment: @user1384726 - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: @user1384726 - I don't claim to understand what you are using this framework for.  socket.io is used to create a lasting socket connection between a client and a server.  The code you referred to in your question is the server-side of the code.  Somewhere there is a client-side that is connecting to this server.  I don't know if that's another part of the framework or if that's supposed to be in your own client code somewhere.

Comment: @user1384726 - Elsewhere in that Github repository, I see this: https://github.com/openhab/openhab-cloud/blob/e14f6d5da978688b4ffe1dbb35c6e9b5d4bd67ae/tests/openhabconsole.js#L53

Comment: So basically what I am trying to do is to trace the flow

Comment: @user1384726 - Well that code looks like it is sharing some request information with a specific connected client.  It's a notification scheme where the client is on the other end of a socket.io connection, probably on another computer and perhaps an agent listening for particular events.

Comment: Thank you. Say io.sockets.in(req.openhab.uuid).emit('request', { is server side. So you are saying socket.on('connecttion' is supposed to be the other side, client side, NOT the server side as 'emit' call. Am I correct to say that?

Comment: @user1384726 - No.  Those are both server-side pieces of code.  `var socket = io.connect(someUrl)` would be an example of client-side code connecting to a server.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Given that socket.on('request' should be on server side, however, somehow I can NOT find it in the code, how should I do to trace the flow at point of emit call?

Comment: @user1384726 - `socket.on('request', ...)` is code for a socket.io client.  That's what my answer already says.  Please ask more specific questions if you don't understand what I've already written rather than ask something I've already written an answer for.  `io.sockets.in(req.openhab.uuid).emit('request',...)` and `io.on('connection', ...)` are server-side.

Comment: @user1384726 -  What is it you're trying to do with openhab-cloud?  Perhaps we need to go back to basic fundamentals.  I've already explained that sending the request message allows a listening client (probably on the other end of a network connection) to know that a specific event occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the point.

From server, sending the request message allows a listening client (probably on the other end of a network connection) to know that a specific event occurred.